# Use regex to remove a substring that matches a beginning of a substring through the following comma

Tags: python, regex

I haven't found any helpful Regex tools to help me figure this complicated pattern out.

I have the following string:

```
Myfirstname Mylastname, Department of Mydepartment, Mytitle, The University of Me; 4-1-1, Hong,Bunk, Tokyo 113-8655, Japan E-mail:my.email@example.jp, Tel:00-00-222-1171,  Fax:00-00-225-3386
```

I am trying to learn enough Regex patterns to remove the substrings one at a time:

`E-mail:my.email@example.jp`

`Tel:00-00-222-1171`

`Fax:00-00-225-3386`

So I think the correct pattern would be to remove a given word (ie., "E-mail", "Tel") all the way through the following comma.

**Is type of dynamic pattern possible in Regex?**

I am performing the match in **Python**, however, I don't think that would matter too much.

Also, I know the data string *looks* comma separated, and it is. However there is no guarantee of preserving the order of those fields. That's why I'm trying to use a Regex match.

Comment: Please add your code to the question :)

Comment: Is `rf'({word}.*?),'` what you need? `word` is a variable containing the relevant word, and it then matches all characters up to the first occurrence of a comma. You can retrieve the match with `match.group(1)` (`match = re.search(pattern, string)`).

Comment: @no_hex I'm just using an online regex tester right now. No code to speak of.

Comment: I don't think you need regexp for this. Use `split(',')` to split it into fields at the comma delimiters, then match the beginning of each field with `startswith()`

Comment: Your real problem would be if there are fields with names containing a comma. University names may have this, for example.

Comment: @Brett, should comma also be removed n matches, I'm about the gaps between commas if those fields are in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
<YOUR_WORD>.*?(?=(,|($)))
```

Explanation:

- It looks for the word specified in `<YOUR_WORD>` placeholder
- It looks for any kind of character afterwards
- The search stops when it hits one of the two options:

  - It finds the character `,`
  - It finds an end of the line

So:

```
E-mail.*?(?=(,|($)))
```

Will result in:

```
E-mail:my.email@example.jp
```

And

```
Fax.*?(?=(,|($)))
```

Will result in:

```
Fax:00-00-225-3386
```

If there are edge cases it misses - I would like to know, and whether it affects the performance/ is necessary.